# Linux program to take newest ftp file and send to other ftp server

Tags: python, ftp

I was wondering if it was possible to take the newest files uploaded to an ftp server and send them to another ftp server. BUT, every file can only be sent once. If you can do this in python that would be nice, I know intermediate python. EXAMPLE:

2:14 PM file.txt is uploaded to the server. the program takes the file and sensd it to another server. 
2:15 PM example.txt is uploaded to the server. the program takes just that file and sends it to another server.

I have searched online for this but cant find anything. Please help!

Comment: Looks like a job for [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) and [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). No need for programming at all.

Comment: Thanks ill check them out

Comment: and home can i set this up?

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you already know python, I will give you some conceptual hints. Basically, you are looking for a one-way synchronisation. The main problem with this task is to make your program detect new files. The simplest way to do this is to create a database (note that by database I mean a way of storing data, not necessarly a specialized database). For example, a text file. In this database, each file will be recorded. Periodically, check the database with the current files (the basic ls or something similar will do). If a new file appears (meaning that there are files that are not in database), upload them.

This is the basic idea. You can improve it by using multi threading, some checks if a file has modified and so on.

EDIT: This is a programming way. As it has been suggested in comments, there are also some software solutions that will do this for you.

Comment: Ahh right what I will do is when a new file is uploaded, record the path to the txt file (ill make the program for that), then have python upload that file at that dir, then clear the text file and delete the file. It can look up 10 seconds to be sure it doesn't record a file twice because of lag.

Comment: My idea was to keep in a text file the uploaded files, so you don't have to delete them...